# Debezium Connect on Docker unable to start container because HmacSHA256 issue

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I want to run `debezium/connect`  on docker in Oracle Linux 7.

It was running well when I tried it on VM in my local PC. But when I run the container with same image using the same properties in Development Server (also Oracle Linux 7), it always exited.

The only different thing is I installed docker and its dependencies manually using RPMs because there is no internet connection for the server. I just installed the docker-engine until it worked without updating other packages.

Here is the command I used:

```
docker run --name connect -d -p 8083:8083 \ 
 BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 \ 
 GROUP_ID=1 \ 
 CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-configs \ 
 OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-offsets \ 
 ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=10.1.21.2 \ 
 --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka \ 
 debezium/connect
```

I checked at /var/lib/docker/containers, it has the following error:

> {"log":"2023-05-14 04:52:17,088 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed]\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-05-14T04:52:17.090206573Z
> "}
> {"log":"java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-05-14T04:52:17.090223351Z"}
> {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:95)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-05-14T04:52:17.090227317Z"}
> {"log":"\u0009at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-05-14T04:52:17.090231636Z"}
> {"log":"**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value HmacSHA256 for configuration inter.worker.key.generation.algorithm: HmacSHA256 KeyGenerator not available**\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-05-14T04:52:17.090239354Z"}